# Need a custom progress bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, spinner

I want to achieve something of this sort
video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ep78y0fecNY8GVOCWFEo_unSSPnPfSUt/view?usp=sharing

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

set indeterminateDrawable to progress_icon

progress_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="300" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="420" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="480" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="540" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_sparkspinner_css"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fromDegrees="-60"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="600" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Using the above code it comes like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GhdzlTTUmigwpL2MvswRrQxGitA32BL9/view?usp=sharing

ic_sparkspinner_css.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="44dp"
    android:height="44dp"
    android:viewportWidth="44"
    android:viewportHeight="44">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21.9878,0C20.3224,0 19,0.9453 19,2.0896L20.0286,13.7562C20.1265,14.4527 20.9837,15 21.9878,15C23.0163,15 23.8735,14.4527 23.9959,13.7562L25,2.0896C25,0.9453 23.6776,0 21.9878,0Z"
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:fillType="evenOdd"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

Its not coming as required, I am new to android animation, what is best way to approach it? If anyone can help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create custom progressbar which is little tough for newcomers why not use lottie library. They have great collection of progressbar and loading animations

Github Library: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android
lottie files to use: https://lottiefiles.com/

Comment: Can you help me in correcting the above code.. I don’t want to use external library please help